# Why is making a Ramdisk for /tmp a good Thing?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, ssd, ram, tmp

Many people recommend setting up a Ramdisk for the /tmp directory.
What Use do I get from it?
Is there any difference when using an all SSD / all HDD Sytem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the File System Hierarchy Standard states

> Programs must not assume that any files or directories in /tmp are
>   preserved between invocations of the program.

http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html#TMPTEMPORARYFILES

So this data need not be kept and probably should be cleared out often. However most modern Linux distributions now map /tmp -> /run/tmp/ instead of some complicated per application exit purging and /run MUST be cleared every boot so this is just easier.

> This directory contains system information data describing the system
>   since it was booted.

http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html#VARRUNRUNTIMEVARIABLEDATA

Most distributions therefor implement /run (and therefor /tmp -> /run/tmp) as a tmpfs. This ensures any applications that don't cleanup their files in /tmp get purged every boot.

Comment: What distributions implement `/tmp` as `/run/tmp`? I just checked an Arch and an Ubuntu 16.04.03 system and neither of them seems to (but maybe I don't know how to check, how would I check?). How exactly would that work? As a symlink? A `mount --bind`?

Comment: How do this answer relates to ubuntu?

Comment: FWIW - you can check if a system is mounted tmpfs with `findmt` , example, Ubuntu  17.10, `findmnt --target /run` yields `/run   tmpfs  tmpfs` I do not know when the change was made, probably with systemd. /tmp is not tmpfs , but, because it is a sub directory of /run , /run/tmp is tmpfs . `findmnt --target /tmp` yields `/      /dev/sda1 ext4` Same results with systemd-private* , noting in /tmp if tempfs nor is /tmp linked to /run/tmp `drwxrwxrwt  14 root root      4096 Nov 10 09:09 tmp` , /tmp is a directory

Comment: Not sure about other distros ;) . In addition , not all distros ,  apps , or services honor the FHS standards. data in /tmp should be cleared at reboot and /var/tmp should be preserved and /run/tmp is tmpfs so by definition will be cleared at boot regardless of what apps want. Not all apps honor these standards (search launchpad for bugs with /tmp and you will find specifics).

Comment: I think that the original question is about the usage of ram. What you write is correct, but why I should waste the ram for such files?